# Is writing in FeRAM memory cell destructive?

Tags: integrated-circuit, memory, ram, vlsi, non-volatile-memory

I have read that writing in Ferroelectric random access memory is not destructive. But in a WL||PL memory architecture, if I try to write a '0' in a cell and the adjacent cell holds a '1', shouldn't it damage the stored value of that adjacent cell? I mean, both the WL and the PL of the adjacent cell is high also and BL is floating, and due to the parasitic capacitance of the BL, shouldn't it affect the polarization and therefore, the stored value? I mean we perform the read operation based on the charge sharing of parasitic capacitance, right?

Answer (score 1):

Some DRAM can be affected in that way, because storing a charge on a capacitor is a linear operation, and the effects of perturbations accumulate.

But the [ferroelectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity) material used in FRAM is bistable, and requires a certain minimum energy to change state. If any individual perturbation isn't enough to change the state, then the effects of multiple perturbations do not accumulate.